# Bash syntax for downloading linked files and preserving directory structure

Tags: curl, sed

I need to download from a webpage all linked files of specific type, e.g. pdf, and put them in folders according to the site structure.
I use curl and filter it with sed to create urls for download:

```
curl http://site/webpage | grep pdf | sort -u | sed 's/html code to exclude//' | sed 's/pdf">.*/pdf/' ~/urllist.txt
```

I create folders with:

```
sed -e 's#http.*com/##' | sed -e 's#/.*##' | sed -e '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' < ~/urllist.txt > ~/dirlist.txt
cat ~/dirlist.txt | xargs mkdir
```

Then I can download them putting all files in one folder:

```
cat ~/urllist.txt | xargs -n1 curl -O
```

So I have two questions:

1. I'm stuck with `mv` command. How to move downloaded files to folders according to the list?
2. I'm sure there is a much more elegant solution in MacOS Sierra by combining all commands in one string, without xcode/wget/homebrew/etc. I'd be glad to see it.

Individual URLs look like `http://site/folder/file.extension` so e.g. `https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D700_en.pdf`

P.S. I know that wget makes all this without any problem but it is not an option as Xcode can't be installed.

Comment: It woud help if you could show what the individual URLs look like before and after your wacky chain of `sed` scripts. You should be able to reduce it down to at least one less by combining `sed x | sed y` into `sed -e x -e y`

Comment: As an aside, `wget` may do more or less what you're asking out of the box. It's hard to get it to do *exactly* what you want unless your use case coincides with the `wget` maintainer's, so you'll probably need some postprocessing; but its default behavior in some modes is to create a directory tree.

Comment: individual URLs look like `http://site/folder/file.extension` For e.g. `https://cdn-10.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D700_en.pdf` and about wget I specifically opted it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your `sed` script substantially by realizing that `mkdir -p` will create a hierarchy of directories if necessary. In fact, you don't need full regex here; the substitutions are simple enough that the shell's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) facility is sufficient,

```
while read -r url; do
    # trim http://hostname/
    path=${url#http://*/}
    # remove last component
    dir=${path%/*}
    # create directories if necessary
    mkdir -p "$dir" || continue
    # dowload into dir
    ( cd "$dir"; curl -s "$url" )
done <urllist.txt
```

We are relying on the fact that `*` in this context always matches the shortest possible string.

`mkdir` could fail if the URL contained some characters which are disallowed in directory names (I vaguely recall colon is problematic on MacOS...?) and we skip that URL if this happens (you should get an error message with details from `mkdir`.)

`curl` is being run in a subshell (that's what the parentheses do) so that we can `cd` to the directory we created without the need to `cd` back when we are done. (There are some corner cases where this is nontrivial.) The parent script's working directory remains unaffected by anything the subshell does.

I added an `-s` option to make `curl` less noisy; you can obviously take it out again if you like, though that makes it more likely that you will miss any error messages from the script when you run it on many URLs.

As an aside, notice that `cat` on a single file is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html); you can pass a file to `xargs` with

```
xargs mkdir <dirlist.txt
```

but with this, `dirlist.txt` is no longer useful or necessary.

You might want to remove the redirection after `done` and have the script read the URLs from standard input; then, you can pipe the URL generator script right into this downloader script without the need to save the URLs in an intermediate file. (If you still want the file for bookkeeping or whatever, add `tee urllist.txt` in the middle of the pipeline;

```
./geturls |
tee urllist.txt |
./downloadurls
```

assuming you saved your script snippets as files with these names and an appropriate [shebang line,](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and marked them executable.)

Comment: Coincidentally, this is one of those cases where you really need to use lowercase for your script's private variables (which is a recommendation which is frequently violated); if you used `PATH` here you would overwrite the system `PATH`, causing the shell to no longer be able to find `mkdir`, `curl`, etc.

Comment: Thx for detailed and clear answer. I’m fully satisfied.